# screenshot in surfaceview android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, surfaceview

i try so many solution from here but still not get a screenshot of whole screen, only one can be generated to sdcard.

this is my code :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Set the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfacelayout);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        final View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagecontrol,
                null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePoster);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        poster = i.getStringExtra("url_poster");

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(poster, imageview);
        System.out.println(poster);

        Button buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                View v = viewControl.getRootView();
                v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
                String dest = Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                        + File.separator
                        + "Camera"
                        + File.separator
                        + "IMG_"
                        + new DateFormat()
                                .format("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", new Date()) + ".jpg";
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Writing to: " + dest);
                File file = new File(dest);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(APP_TAG, "Error taking screenshot.", e);
                } finally {
                    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
```

im still get blackscreen and just only one layout get screenshot, not a whole screen...

how to get a screenshot of the whole screen?

i want to be able get screenshot without root of course....

thanks

Comment: So you're trying to capture both the app UI and the camera preview?  They're on different layers, so you'll need to capture them separately and composite them together.  It might be simpler to replace the `SurfaceView` with a `TextureView`, which will result in all of the pixels appearing on a single layer.

Comment: yes, but how i can composite them together? i tried so many but still cant get it. thanks